# PHP - for loops through associative array

Tags: php, loops, post, associative-array

I have an associative array $_POST, which has 3 key value pairs (There are other key value pairs which I am not interested in).

```
$_POST[Var1]
$_POST[Var2]
$_POST[Var3]
```

How do I use a for loop to loop through and echo the values in each?

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++){
    echo $_POST['Var' . '$i']; 
}
```

This does not seem to work.

Answer (score 5):

Get rid of the single quotes around `$i` as that makes it a literal string and your variable is not interpolated:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++){
    echo $_POST['Var' . $i]; 
}
```

This is basic PHP. I *strongly* recommend [reading the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) to learn more about the fundamentals of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Check this. While using php varibles dont put upper commas for the variables.

```
  <?php
    $_POST["file1"];
    $_POST["file2"];
    $_POST["file3"];
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++){
        echo $_POST['file'.$i]; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this way:

```
$_POST["Var{$i}"];
```